# Inno Setup: Show message to notify user to close specific application before install

Tags: inno-setup

I need code that show message page or button to notify user "Save your Drawings Autocad will close automatically"

I found code that force close the AutoCAD once I press Install button.

```
 [Code]
  var ResultCode: integer;
  function PrepareToInstall(var NeedsRestart: Boolean): String;
  begin
    if (msgbox('Please Save your Drawings and close Autocad', mbConfirmation, MB_Ok) = IDOk) then
    function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
    var ErrorCode: Integer;
    begin
    ShellExec('open',
    'taskkill.exe',
    '/f /im acad.exe','',SW_HIDE,ewNoWait,ErrorCode);
    ShellExec('open',
    'tskill.exe',
    ' ACAD','',SW_HIDE,ewNoWait,ErrorCode);
    result := True;
    end;
        end;
```

Comment: thank martin for your help I tried your suggest Inno Setup - Display MessageBox to run additional file.and i can't make it work well with my program.sorry martin i'm beginner in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should be like:

```pascal
[Code]

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
  ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
  if MsgBox('Save your Drawings and close Autocad', mbConfirmation, MB_OK) = IDOK then
  begin
    ShellExec('open', 'taskkill.exe', '/f /im acad.exe','', SW_HIDE, ewNoWait, ErrorCode);
    ShellExec('open', 'tskill.exe', ' ACAD', '', SW_HIDE, ewNoWait, ErrorCode);
    Result := True;
  end
    else
  begin
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: thanks a lot martin can you guide me how to learn inno setup code,not from inno setup help, any resources books videos,I will be thankful.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know any other resource except the help. Of course some intro to a generic Pascal programming helps.